# IBM MQ not returning Correlation ID

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I am putting messages on a Websphere MQ for an application over which I have no control or documentation.  I need the correlation id to be returned in the response
and despite testing various flags, the correlation id is always null upon return. Is this entirely up to the responding application to set this field? Is there a way to force the field to be set by the MQ itself?

Comment: I think you are sending an HTTP request and getting a response.  Is the status in the response a 200 OK?  If 200 then your query isn't returning any data.  If you are getting a 400/500 as a status your request has errors.

Comment: It is not a HTTP interface, it uses the IBM MQ client for .NET.  I successfully post messages, but they are not updated with the correlation id.

Comment: It is up to the replying application to populate the Correlation Id field. If it is null, then you need to speak to the team responsible for the replying application and ask them why it is not being populated.

Comment: Learn your Network layers.  IBM MQ client is the application.  The protocol is HTTP.  See https://docs.bmc.com/docs/mvmm91/testing-and-checking-the-status-of-the-mq-and-ibm-mq-connection-configuration-1034644828.html

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the pedantry, but that link and your comment remain irrelevant to the discussion.